# JQuery Ajax Post - reduce call latency to offline server

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, post

I am building an application with online and offline support. When the application starts i check to see if my node.js server is up and running and based on this i change the isOnline variable accordingly.

Here is my ajax call:

```
var request = jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: mainURL
});
request.done(function (data) {
    isOnline = true;                
});
request.fail(function (data) {
    isOnline = false;                 
});
```

The problem is that when the server is online the request has a latency of 316 ms, but when is offline the request has a latency of 2.09 s. Why it takes so long when is offline because it affects my application.

Comment: You want to use the AJAX timeout property, and set it to some interval of your choice. Note that if your connection is slow or taking a while to respond, it will just say your server is offline.

Comment: To add to this, use this with caution, as you are _assuming_ the server will **always** respond within the set time.